# How to make variable in method global?

Tags: android

For example I have a method like this. If you see the String 'tablenumber' I want to be able to use it in a later function such as a onclick button so I can send the contents of it to a different activity. But if I use this variable outside the method it's not recognised. How do I go about this.

```
{
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {

                String tablenumber = (String) arg0.getSelectedItem();

            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can make the scope of your variable global for your whole activity like this

```
public class Xyz extends Activity {



    String tablenumber;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.abc);

}
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {

            tablenumber = (String) arg0.getSelectedItem();

        }

}
```

Comment: Can you explain to me what Private and Final means?

Comment: @Ed Briscoe   To declare a constant field, you use the final keyword and initialize its value.
You can assign a value to a final variable only once. If you try to reassign a new
value to a final variable that has already been assigned a value, you will get a
compiler error.

Comment: private variables and methods are only accessible in the class
file they are defined in—they are not accessible even to subclasses.

Answer (score 2):

make it a field in your activity class. if you're using eclipse, select your local variable and use Ctrl/1 or Cmd/1, then choose "convert local variable to field"

Comment: Can you explain to me what Private and Final means?

Comment: the `final` modifier means a variable will never change, so it's safe to use in other threads or in anonymous class instances. `private` means that a variable can only be used in the class where it's defined.

Comment: see [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) for a good tutorial on access levels.

Answer (score 2):

You should use global variable.

```
    {
        String tablenumber;
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {

            tablenumber = (String) arg0.getSelectedItem();

        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        }
    });
```